# Reusing AUTO INCREMENT ID

Tags: mysql

I would like to reuse an AUTO INCREMENT ID that is being deleted. am using the MySQL database.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If you're running out of space on the column, it's safer to increase the size of the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field rather than reuse the old ids.

Comment: either you can set AUTO_INCREMENT id every time when record delete or you can pick highest id value and @ insertion time insert incremented value in id field.

Comment: @Ajay how can I get the id of recently deleted AUTO INCREMENT ID, so that I can create  an external procedure to do the same

Comment: may be my ans will help you :).

Comment: is it working for you or not??

Comment: @Ajay Its working.But I guess u dint get my exact problem.

Comment: as i understand you want auto incremented id or something else?

Comment: I need a procedure to get the AUTO INCREMENT ID of last deleted field.using this ID, i could reuse the deleted AUTO INCREMENT ID. 

For example I have a table of 2 field name and ID, ID being the primary key
 
ID NAME
1 AB
2 CD
3 EF
4 GH
5 IJ
6 KL
7 MN

This is my table and if I delete the field where ID = 5 and NAME = IJ, i need to get the ID of the deleted field and should be able to reuse the ID 5 in some other case. 

Hope u can help me out!.

Comment: Why do you want to reuse the IDs? As Tom says, it's generally better to just increase the size of the field, unless your delete : insert ratio is over half

Comment: but what if when I delete a mass number of entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id + 1 FROM TableName t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableName t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id + 1) limit 0,1
```

Answer (score 0):

To find that you can use this

```
SELECT Auto_increment FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name='tableName'  AND table_schema = 'dataBaseName';
```